# Test if PayPal Security Changes will work

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

According to [this](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1913), paypal developers need to update their machine. My question is, how can we know that our application is ready for these changes?

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't need to update anything. I was already using Java 8, and HTTPS for the verification postback: when my first IPN after the upgrade came through, it just worked.

Comment: mine is also currently working. My problem is when the paypal applied those changes, will my app be working properly? I once read that paypal's sandbox is already using the security changes but not the live. Is it true? Coz, I can know now that my app will work properly in live's changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can check your SSL details using [this tool](https://cryptoreport.geotrust.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp).  You just need to make sure it's showing SHA256 and TLS 1.2 for the enabled protocol.  It will also give you details about any potential vulnerabilities you need to fix up in general.

For the IPN change that's really just up to you to make sure you've made the change.  Within the IPN script you POST data back to PayPal.  You need to make sure you're using https:// on the URL that you're POSTing back to.  They will reject http://.

That's really all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks, the site says that we are using SHA256 and TLS 1.2. The thing is, how can I be sure that it will work? Does this mean I'm good for the changes already?

Oh, the IPN. We are using WooCommerce and I think its IPN is not working. But I'm pretty sure that it's using https. here's the log.

`Generating payment form for order 8822. Notify URL: https://<mydomain>/wc-api/WC_Gateway_Paypal/`

Comment: Check your PayPal IPN history to verify IPNs are getting sent, and if there's a failure happening you'd see that code represented in the IPN History as well.

Comment: I know this is a different issue from this thread. I saw in IPN History `Delivery status: Failed`. I looked at the `access_log` from apache logs and saw that there is a 500 error. there are no logs in `error_log` also. The only log I get is `06-21-2016 @ 08:37:49 - Generating payment form for order 8823. Notify URL: https://<domain>/wc-api/WC_Gateway_Paypal/` from the woocommerce's paypal IPN log when I clicked the checkout button. At this point, I don't know what to do next. Where can I find the cause of this error?

Comment: Take a look at this post on [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).  Follow those steps and you should be able to track down the issue.

Comment: From the first step, I got it where the woocommerce's logs from IPN is working. but has `Received invalid response from PayPal`. And I thought about the PayPal sandbox's. I put there `https://localhost/?wc-api=WC_Gateway_Paypal`. Maybe the localhost is the problem, isn't it?. I may need a staging environment to test this right?

Comment: Yes, "localhost" to their server is themselves.  ;)